# Get the character that a Unicode code point corresponds

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

For a Computer Science class, we've got to make a python program that converts a character into it's Unicode Codepoint (the bin/hex number which is the reference to the character). Is there a function out there which can do this, like how the `ord()` function converts to ASCII and is there a function which does the reverse, turning a Unicode codepoint into a character?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like `ord()` works for any Unicode codepoint. And `unichr()` would perform the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

In Python3, if you know the unicode code point of a character, for example, [`我`](https://graphemica.com/%E6%88%91) with Unicode code point `\u6211`, you can get the character with:

```
chr(0x6211)
```

Answer (score 1):

The builtin function `ord` also works for unicode characters both in Python2 and Python3.

#### Python 3

```
>>> c='\U0010ffff'
>>> ord(c)
1114111
```

#### Python 2

```
>>> c=u'\U0010ffff'
>>> ord(c)
1114111
```

#### Difference between Python 2 and 3

The difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is when you go the other way around.

In Python 3, the function `chr` can take any code, ascii or unicode, and outputs the character.

In Python 2, the function `chr` is for extended ascii (code 0 to 255) and the function `unichr` is for unicode.

This is due to the fact that in Python 2, unicode and ascii strings were two different types.

#### Hexadecimal

If you need to get the character code in hexadecimal, you can use `hex`.

```
>>> hex(1114111)
'0x10ffff'
```

#### Binary

If you need to get the character in binary, you can use `bin`.

```
>>> bin(1114111)
'0b100001111111111111111'
```

Comment: `chr()` in Python 2 works for any byte value (0..255), not only the range of ASCII characters (0..127).